# Notification that a JOB did not start in SQL Server Agent 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

We are able to send notification regarding failure/success of a job but if a job does not start on its scheduled time can we create a script which will send a notification to my mail box saying that the "JOB did not start'?

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191130.aspx), below are the only cases which can be notified. So, `JOB Doesn't start` isn't even in the list; which means that you can't set a notification for that.

But my thinking is that, If you know that in a day you are supposed to get N email notification for N jobs, you can check that and find out which job didn't run.

> - When the job succeeds to notify the operator when the job completes    successfully.
> - When the job fails to notify the operator when the job completes       unsuccessfully.
> - When the job completes to notify the operator regardless of       completion status.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 J.NAME AS 'JOBNAME',
 MSDB.DBO.AGENT_DATETIME(RUN_DATE, RUN_TIME) AS 'RUNDATETIME'
INTO #TEMP
FROM MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBS J 
INNER JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBHISTORY H 
 ON J.JOB_ID = H.JOB_ID 
WHERE J.ENABLED = 1  --ONLY ENABLED JOBS
ORDER BY JOBNAME, RUNDATETIME DESC

IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM #TEMP
    WHERE JOBNNAME = 'JOBNAME'
    AND RUNDATETIME = 'RUNDATETIME')
        BEGIN

            SEND AN EMAIL

        END
```

There's no simple way to do this, but you can query the job history tables to check if the job start time has been logged. If it hasn't you can use an IF expression to send you an email.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks boss...i have a question though. For running this query do i need to schedule a new job in SQL Server Agent or i can place this query as a new step in the existing job itself.

Comment: If the job doesn't start, then no steps will take place. This will need to go into a separate job and you can have it check every 15 minutes. You could put extra checks in place to see if 1. It's already alerted you, 2. if the scheduled time has not passed yet then to ignore. This is all fairly easily implemented in T-SQL with it's dynamic capabilities.